# Is it sufficient just to have the Custom Username validator in the web.config endpoint BindingConfiguration?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a Customer Username/Password validator.  Is it sufficient enough to have it in the endpoints bindingConfiguration attribute in web.config or do I need to explicitly call it in the Service method.  I noticed when I don't call it a Service operation, it doesn't get called.  Am I doing something wrong?

This is how I have my bindings section defined:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomAuthentication">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This is how I have my service node defined:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator" name="Test.TestService">
```

My endpoint attribute has its BindingConfiguration = "CustomAuthentication"

This is how I have a behavior in my ServiceBehaviors defined:

```
<behavior name="CustomValidator">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Test.CustomUserNameValidator, FuzionSync"/>

        <serviceCertificate findValue="MyWebSite" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>

        </serviceCredentials>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>

    </behavior>
```

When I run the wcf test client to invoke the service call, it doesn't even call the Validate method.  The only way I get it to call is if I put it in an operation to be called explicitly.

Comment: If I am right you will need to use these as a credential, before connecting to wcf service.

Comment: @BreakHead, I am confused on your response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify this both in the binding configuration and in the service behavior. This is how it looks in one of our projects (the important parts are `clientCredentialType="UserName"` and the `<serviceCredentials>` element):

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SSLWithCustomAuthentication">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                 negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="customAuthenticationBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication 
          userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Namespace.YourValidator, AssemblyName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and then have your service use `behaviorConfiguration="customAuthenticationBehavior"`.

Note that I don't think WCF lets you use UserName authentication without SSL.

Comment: I update my post.  I have a temporary SSL Cert on m local machine.

Comment: Looks good to me. By the way, does the service operation itself get called when the client connects, or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: When I run it through the WCF Test Client and click Invoke, it returns data, but the Validate method is not called.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Looks like the service somehow doesn't "notice" your UserName configuration, then - not sure why. (I seem to recall that we had some IIS-related problems that were resolved by adding `<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>` to Web.config and `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]` to the service class, but I'm not sure if it was related to this). Otherwise, I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid.