# What is the bindingConfiguration attribute responsible for in a BasicHttpBinding endpoint config?

Tags: wcf

So I am working with configuring endpoints for a WCF service.  I have almost no experience with services as a whole, but have been plopped in the middle of a project that uses them.  I roughly understand what each attribute in the endpoint is doing except for one.  "bindingConfiguration".

Here's an obscured version of my code (actual information is proprietary):

```
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/SomeService.svc"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService"
           contract="SomeService.ICoreService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService" />
```

Here's MSDN's take on it (as in they don't specifically address it).

[Microsoft's incomplete MSDN Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx)

Of course Stackoverflow has a few questions containing a string match for "bindingConfiguration" but none explicetely address my question:

[Most relative (I think) Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993024/is-it-sufficient-just-to-have-the-custom-username-validator-in-the-web-config-end)

Any ideas on what this is used for?

In the interest of learning I am willing to take a stab and be wrong here.  I think it has something to with authentication or security.  On Inspection of the Interface I notice nothing pertaining to this either.

Any help would be great!

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your bindings section, you can have multiple "configurations" for the same binding type (in your case, basicHttpBinding). The binding configuration chooses among them which one to use.

In MSDN, you should try to find the reference for [`<endpoint>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731320.aspx) (since bindingConfiguration is is attribute), that will have a definition of what the attribute is supposed to do.

In the example below, the service defines two endpoints, both using `basicHttpBinding`. One of them is exposed over "normal" HTTP, the other is exposed over HTTPS. The `bindingconfiguration` attribute is the one which tells WCF which configuration to use.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SimpleBasic">
                <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicOverHttps">
                <security mode="Transport"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
            <endpoint address="ep"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="SimpleBasic"
                      contract="MyNamespace.IService" />
            <endpoint address="secure"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="BasicOverHttps"
                      contract="MyNamespace.IService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Your example makes perfect sense.  Thank you for your quick reply.  So basically you have additional xml configuring the binding you specify.  Implying the default basicHttpBinding was not exactly what it needed.  I was able to locate several <bindings> inside different files inside the solution, but not in that particular service project.  What I am curious about now is can the configurations for these bindings be located in a seprate config file?  I was not able to find any definitions exactly matching the name of my bindingConfiguration in the file, or the project really.  Lingering code?

Comment: Probably. I think if you have (in IIS) a web.config in a directory, any web.config on subdirectories would inherit the configuration of the parent (I haven't tried it), so if this is the case it's possible that the missing configuration was from one of the parent configurations. But it's likely that's just some bad config.